# do while loop is not breaking properly java

Tags: java

```
public class DoWhile1 {
    private static int grade, total, sum, average;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

        do {
            System.out.println("Please enter a grade b/w 0-100:");
            grade = sc.nextInt();

            if (grade >= 0 && grade <= 100) {
                total++;
                sum = sum + grade;

                System.out.println("Please enter another grade or 999 to break:");
            } else {    
                System.out.println("Incorrect value, please reenter grade:");
            }
        } while (grade != 999);

        average = sum/total;
    }
}
```

This loop is suppose to break when 999 is entered, but when entered before breaking it output error message from the else inside the loop.  It's not suppose to output anything before breaking.
we tried moving the while part of the loop, but it did not affect anything.  We can't see any other problems with it.

Comment: So, the above prints the else part before breaking and you don't want that to happen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change `else` to `else if (grade != 999)` when you are displaying the error.

Do it as follows:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {
    private static int grade, total, sum, average;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        do {
            System.out.println("Please enter a grade b/w 0-100:");
            grade = sc.nextInt();
            if (grade >= 0 && grade <= 100) {
                total++;
                sum = sum + grade;
                System.out.println("Please enter another grade or 999 to break:");
            } else if (grade != 999) {
                System.out.println("Incorrect value, please reenter grade:");
            }
        } while (grade != 999);
        average = sum / total;
    }
}
```

**A sample run:**

```
Please enter a grade b/w 0-100:
24
Please enter another grade or 999 to break:
Please enter a grade b/w 0-100:
999
```

Answer (score 3):

Your do-while is working correctly - the course of action is the following:

[image]

1. In a `do-while`, the statements are always executed at least once. So you enter the `do { }`, and fall into the `else` condition, since 999 is greater than 0 and not smaller than 100.
2. You then evaluate the expression `grade != 999` -> this is false, since `grade == 999`.
3. You don't do the `do { }` again and come out of the `do-while`.

To achieve the behavior that you want, you will need to add an additional statement inside the `do { }`, e.g:

```
...
if (grade == 999) {
   break; //or print statement
}
else if (grade >= 0 && grade <= 100) {
...
```

Answer (score 2):

You could wrapp the message by another `if` that checks if the number is not 999.

```java
else
{
    if (grade != 999) {
        System.out.println("Incorrect value, please reenter grade:");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could check input value for `grade == 999` and exist in case it equals to:

```
public static double getAverage() {
    try (Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in)) {
        int total = 0;
        int sum = 0;
        int average = 0;

        while (true) {
            System.out.print("Please enter a grade b/w 0-100 (or 999 to exit): ");
            int grade = scan.nextInt();

            if (grade >= 0 && grade <= 100) {
                total++;
                sum += grade;
            } else if (grade == 999)
                break;
            else
                System.out.println("Incorrect value\n");
        }

        return (double)sum / total;
    }
}
```